# Auto Scroll through content on Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I've written a basic visualforce page that displays some content on a force.com site. (I'm very new to this so quite please so far). This is a test so there are limited results from the select statement but in live there could be more than a whole page worth so I was wondering is there a way to set an autoscroll of some description so its tracking or moving up the page constantly?
[image: site page displaying results]

```
<apex:page controller="pulsecontacts" standardStylesheets="True" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
<style>
                     .bPageBlock {
                                background-color: #DCDCDC!important;
                     }
              </style> 
<apex:pageBlock >
<h1> Pulse Scores Received this Week</h1>
   <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="contact" columnsWidth="15%,15%,15%,15%,15%,25%">
        <apex:column headerValue="Client" value="{!contact.Account_name__c}"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!contact.name}"/> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Pulse Score" style="text-align:left" value="{!contact.TUQ_Score__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Pulse Category" style="text-align:left" value="{!contact.Pulse_Category__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="Date Received" style="text-align:left" value="{!contact.Date_of_Last_Pulse_Score_1__c}"/>
        <apex:column headerValue="How could we get you to a 10?" Value="{!contact.How_could_we_get_you_to_a_10_TUQ__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>    
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Autoscroll or paginate? Pagination is a better solution I guess.

Comment: you know what would be even better.. is some sort of filter. So the data is displayed in a table, could you have a field that allows text to be inputted that filters the table to only display the results?

Comment: Try using jQuery Datatables http://datatables.net/